# Only index.js works in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am actually just getting started with Reactjs. So as i installed all the React packages on my PC using npm, i deleted all the src files which were in it because they were just sample files, i wanted to create on my own, but the problem is that my main js file name was "original.js" while it was demanding that "index.js" can't be found. So i changed my file name to "index.js" and now it works. Can someone tell me how to find the settings where i can see this issue so that i don't have to name my every main rract file as "index.js".
Thank you

Comment: Could you include more detail about your installation process? What packages did you install, what directory were the files you deleted in, and how are you running this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in the web development world (not just React), we use `index.*` files instead of `main.*` files.

If you would like to rename it, you might need to do some complex stuff like ejecting the app from `create-react-app`, and then changing `webpack.config.js`, but that seems way too advanced for you.

Instead I would recommend what most tutorials online say to do, which is keep `index.js` as the entry point of your app and import your Main component into it, like so:

```
// src/index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Main from "./Main";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Main />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```
// src/Main.js
import React from 'react';

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <h1>My main component</h1>
  );
};

export default Main;
```